# Ghostscript interprets pdfmarks and generates incorrect annotations

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I am trying to create a PDF file with bookmarks, links and annotations using Ghostscript 9.10, with the help of this [pdfmark Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdfmark_reference.pdf) and this [pdfmark Recipes](http://www.meadowmead.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/PDFMarkRecipes.pdf) book.

I have a problem when I create the postscript file `in.ps` by printing to the [Ghostscript PDF printer](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/tags/ghostscript-9.02/lib/ghostpdf.inf) a landscape page, then I run `gswin64c.exe @gsparams` with the following two files:

```
=== gsparams ===
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPSFitPage -o out.pdf in.ps pdfmarks

=== pdfmarks ===
[ /Rect [50 50 100 200]
  /SrcPg 1
  /Contents (Some text)
  /DA ([0.5 0 0] rg /Helv 18 Tf)
  /Q 1
  /Border [0 0 2 [20 10]]
  /BS <</S /D /W 2 /D [5 3]>>
  /Color [0.3 1 1]
  /Subtype /FreeText
  /ANN pdfmark
```

The resulting PDF file does contain an annotation, but if I open it with 3 different applications I get 3 different results: Acrobat shows the colored rectangle with border and the rotated text correctly, Chrome shows just an horizontal text, Bluebeam shows the correct rectangle, but the text is horizontal and the border is duplicated.

Is the definition of the `/ANN pdfmark` wrong?

Is Ghostscript not able to correctly interpret the pdfmarks? If so, is there another (possibly free) tool I can use for this?

Comment: "Acrobat shows the colored rectangle with border and the rotated text correctly". That's all there is -- Adobe's own Acrobat is *the* reference, all others are just interpretations.

Comment: @Jongware: My question wasn't about how to read the file, was about how to create the annotations in a reliable way. How can I create an annotation that is reliably rendered on most PDF viewer, just like most PDF editors do?

Comment: You need to supply an appearance stream (/APP if I remember correctly) for reasonably reliable reproduction. If you do not supply this then PDF consumers are required to construct the appearance, and this is (of course) unreliable. Any behaviour is acceptable, including not displaying anything, if you do not supply an appearance. Note that Acrobat generally seems to ignore appearance streams and always constructs its own, so the only truly universal approach is to supply an appearance stream which is identical to the Acrobat one.

Comment: @KenS: I consider this the correct answer. My problem is not on the way I define the annotation nor on the tool I use, Ghostscript. Plus you addressed me to the right direction for the solution to my problem. Thanks.